# Selecting field values starting with A-F and sorting in alphabetical order

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to pull some information from my database which is a collection of videogames. I have a title field that holds the names of the games. I would like to pull all the titles that start with the letters `A-F` (`ABCDEF`) and list them alphabetically. So far this is what I have. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php

    $xboxonequery = "select * from xboxone where title like 'A%'";

    $xboxoneresults = mysql_query( $xboxonequery )
        or die ( "Error obtaining XBox One Games ". mysql_error() );

    for( $i = 0 ; $i < mysql_num_rows( $xboxoneresults ) ; $i++ ){

        $xboxonearray = mysql_fetch_array( $xboxoneresults );        

        echo "<span style='text-align:center;' align='center'>\n";
        echo "<a href='". $xboxonearray['link'] ."'><img src='". $xboxonearray['image'] ."' title='XBox One - ". $xboxonearray['title'] ."' alt='XBox One - ". $xboxonearray['title'] ."'></a>\n";
        echo "</span>\n";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Substrings to the rescue:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE SUBSTR(yourfield, 1, 1) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
```

Comment: THank you so much! This had made things so much easier on me. you DO NOT want to see what i was doing before. I queried each letter :(

Comment: well, you could have had `where yourfield like 'a%" or yourfield like 'b%' etc...`. lots of options. this one is just somewhat compact and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just load them all, in sorted order, and loop on display until you reach the first G* title?